# Board $5\times5$, $25$ cells, $10$ beads with value $1, 15$ with value $0$, calc $P$(At least $1$ row with sum of $3$)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have a board $5\times5$ - $5$ rows, $5$ cols with $25$ cells.

We have $25$ beads, on $10$ of them written the number $1$, on $15$ written the number $0$.

The beads are randomly distributed to the cells of the board.

What is the probability that at least one row will have sum of $3$?

---

What I have tried:

In order to have sum of $3$ In a row, we need to choose $3$ cells out of $5$, namely: $\binom{5}{3}$ And put there $1$’s.

We have $10$ units with the value $1$, therefore, at most we can have $3$ rows with the sum of $3$.

Therefore, we can use inclusion exclusion method and calc: only $1$ row with sum $3 - 2$ rows... + $3$ rows...

So, I get:

$$
\frac{\binom{5}{1}\binom{5}{3} - \binom{5}{2}(\binom{5}{3})^2 + \binom{5}{3}(\binom{5}{3})^3}{\binom{25}{10}}
$$

Which is not the answer so I did something wrong.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to not have any row without a sum of $3$ is when $2$ columns are stacked with all $10$ "$1$" value coins.

So, the answer is $1 -$ this possibility $ = 1- \frac{\binom{5}{2}^5}{\binom{25}{10}}$.

NOTE: This is correct only for the case when at least 1 row has more than equal to 3 beads of value "1".

Comment: This is not correct. A row could have a sum of more than $3$, such as $\{4,2,2,1,1\}$.

Comment: I agree, made an edit to reflect your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for the distribution of the remaining beads in each case:
$$\frac{\binom{5}{1}\binom{5}{3}\binom{20}{7} - \binom{5}{2}(\binom{5}{3})^2\binom{15}{4} + \binom{5}{3}(\binom{5}{3})^3\binom{10}{1}}{\binom{25}{10}}$$